# Working with Charts in motion [Animating chart]

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I have created a areaspline chart using highcharts library and making it animated with play/pause button transition between weeks of data

Ref. https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/176-charts-in-motion/

jsfiddle Ref. https://jsfiddle.net/larsac07/wkev75nL/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=wkev75nL

in the above example, we are animating the chart week wise

dataSet used :

```
dataSequence = [
        {
            name: 'Week 1',
            data: [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Week 2',
            data: [6, 12, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Week 3',
            data: [4, 5, 6, 5, 5, 4, 9]
        }, {
            name: 'Week 4',
            data: [5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6]
        }, {
            name: 'Week 5',
            data: [6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7]
        }, {
            name: 'Week 6',
            data: [8, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 9]
        }, {
            name: 'Week 7',
            data: [9, 10, 4, 10, 9, 9, 9]
        }, {
            name: 'Week 8',
            data: [1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11]
        }, {
            name: 'Week 9',
            data: [11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 11, 11]
        }
    ]
```

I don't want change chart
on play button click I want animate the data points 11 data point for week1 to same data point but different value on y axis for week2

```
xAxis = ["week1", "Week2", ..... ],
yAxis = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], [3,5,7,8,2,1,5,7,6,1,10], ....]
```

on the play button it would transit between `week1` then will go to `week 2` and so till last week number available.

Trying to have something like this Ref. https://aatishb.com/covidtrends/

[image: static chart]

this chart is plotted using this dataset for series

```
Highcharts.chart("container", {
      chart: {
        type: "areaspline"
      },
      tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        valueSuffix: " units"
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: [
          "Week 1",
          "Week 2",
          "Week 3",
          "Week 4",
          "Week 5",
          "Week 6",
          "Week 7"
        ]
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: "Index"
        }
      },
      legend: {
        layout: "horizontal",
        align: "right",
        verticalAlign: "top",
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor:
          (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) ||
          "#FFFFFF"
      },
      plotOptions: {
        areaspline: {
          fillOpacity: 0.5
        }
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "By week",
          data: dataSequence[value].data.slice()
        },
        {
          type: "spline",
          name: "Topic 1",
          data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8]
        },
        {
          type: "spline",
          name: "Topic 2",
          data: [1, 5, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8]
        },
        {
          type: "spline",
          name: "Topic 3",
          data: [3, 7, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8]
        },
        {
          type: "spline",
          name: "Topic 4",
          data: [5, 1, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8]
        },
        {
          type: "spline",
          name: "Topic 5",
          data: [7, 3, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8]
        },
        {
          type: "spline",
          name: "Topic 6",
          data: [9, 2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8]
        },
        {
          type: "spline",
          name: "Topic 7",
          data: [11, 8, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8]
        },
        {
          type: "spline",
          name: "Topic 8",
          data: [13, 11, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8]
        },
        {
          type: "spline",
          name: "Topic 9",
          data: [15, 7, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8]
        },
        {
          type: "spline",
          name: "Topic 10",
          data: [7, 5, 1, 3, 4, 7, 8]
        }
      ],
      title: {
        text: ""
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: "Efficiency Index of Topics"
      }
    });
```

this my update function in react

```
update(increment) {
    var input = $("#play-range")[0];
    var output = $("#play-output")[0];

    if (increment) {
      input.value = parseInt(input.value) + increment;
    }
    output.innerHTML = this.state.dataSequence[input.value].name;
    this.setState({
      value: input.value
    });
    if (input.value >= input.max) {
      // Auto-pause
      this.pause();
      this.setState(
        {
          value: 0
        },
        () => {
          output.innerHTML = this.state.dataSequence[0].name;
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

the whole chart is plotted at once, I need something that it should transit
first, it plots all data points for week1 then week 2 after that week 3 when I click on the play button

Comment: Hi @Vivek Raghav,  I'm sorry, but I don't think I fully understand your question. Do you want to add points on change? Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L0wtuqsr/

Comment: @ppotaczek please check I have updated the question chart I am plotting. maybe this description helps to understand my query

Comment: Thanks, Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L0wtuqsr/1/ Did you mean something like that?

Comment: @ppotaczek yup this helps, I want this transition but as we have plotted the first chart and adding the points, can we start an empty graph and then click on the play we can start plotting the points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start with an empty data and use `addPoint` method in the `update` function:

```
function update(increment) {
    var input = $('#play-range')[0],
        output = $('#play-output')[0],
        increment;

            chart.series[0].addPoint(dataSequence[input.value].data[actualPointIndex]);
    actualPointIndex += increment;

    if (actualPointIndex === 6) {
            actualPointIndex = 0;
        input.value = parseInt(input.value) + increment;
    }

    output.innerHTML = dataSequence[input.value].name; // Output value
    if (input.value >= input.max) { // Auto-pause
        pause($('#play-pause-button')[0]);
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/stpxyfca/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint